# How do I install Ubuntu 12.10 onto a USB

Tags: 12.10, usb

I'm trying to get Ubuntu to work on one of my USBs, first time the install took forever, and was super slow when run off the usb.

so I tried formatting to ext2, still really slow.

anyone know of a step by step guide for installing or running Ubuntu off your USB where it can keep your files? when I try to make a bootable linux usb it wont save any progress when i try the "Try Ubuntu" option. whenever i end the session. Nor does it let me log out or back in of that session.

So anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a USB drive from within Ubuntu.

1. Insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space. (Normally this is formatted as VFAT)
2. Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator.
3. Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app.
4. Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file.
5. Select the file and click 'Open'.
6. Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'. (Make sure to select ("Stored in reserved extra space" so that you save changes across reboots.)
7. That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to restart your computer and begin installing Ubuntu.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Within Windows:

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com ( http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ ). You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.

Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer

1. Select Ubuntu Desktop Edition from the dropdown list.
2. Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file. (Choose the persistence file size.)
3. Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows